# Issue to add socketio to API Express

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i'm trying to add socket.io on my already existing NodeJS API REST Project.

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var router = require('./route/router');
require('dotenv').config();

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(require('helmet')());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization,Content-Type');
    next();
});

router(app);

if (process.env.PRODUCTION === "false") {
    http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function() {
        console.log('8080 ok');
    });

    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
} else {
    const options = {
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./../../etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem'),
        key: fs.readFileSync('./../../etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem')
    };

    https.createServer(options, app).listen(8443, function() {
        console.log('8443 ok');
    });   

    var io = require('socket.io')(https);
}

io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('socketio connected');
});
```

I have no error displayed (server side). But, when I tried on client side, `this.socket = io('ws://localhost:8080/');`, it's not working at all.

I get `GEThttp://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NG6_U6i [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]` browser console.

It seems that something is not ok with the server, but I can't find what's going on

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Try removing listen from var io = require('socket.io').listen(http). Try var io = require('socket.io')(httpServer). And also on client side don't use this.socket = io('http://localhost:8080/'). Instead use this.socket = io('wss://localhost:8080/')

Comment: I tryied but no change @khan and 'wss://localhost:8080' seems to be converted to https https://prnt.sc/u2902w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, you need to include (I don't know if this is the correct word to use) the express server into the socket.io server.

```
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3006;

const app = express();

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App started on port ${port}`)
});

const io = socketio(server, { forceNew: true });
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  // do this
  // do that
});
```

The code above is a skeleton of how express and socket.io are used together. Please modify it as per your needs.

Good luck.

Comment: I modified as `var io = require('socket.io')(http);`. But no change

Comment: If you are using `express` I am not sure why you are using `http` separately. In that case you need to do something like ```const server = require('http').createServer(options);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);``` Receive the output of `http.createServer()` into a variable and pass it into the `socket` server

Comment: If this works, could you please mark the answer as correct? :)